# Given three arrays of data, interpolate

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I made a dataset by measuring three parameters, T, P, and V.  Here's a snippet (below), where a measured `T` of `10` corresponds to a `P` of `5000` and a `V` of `0.986894603`.

```
T      P       V
20    5950    1.253243668
20    3000    1.07099136
22    3000    0.959660925
40    5000    1.011413134
10    5000    0.986894603
```

I wrote a Python code for doing calculations based on the dataset.  But so far I'm restricted to using the values in the dataset.  I would like to be able to enter *any* T and P and get a V via interpolation.

I'm worried that this may be impossible because all the information I have come across so far seems to suggest that the T and P arrays have to vary linearly for this to work in Python. They don't in my case.  However, I'm new to interpolation and maybe I'm not understanding what is going on.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to define what interpolation actually means with your own data. Do you want to do linear regression and then apply that regression to new values? Your data does not look particularly correlated, so I don't see that making sense here, to be honest.

Comment: If you know the relationship, between these (and physicists know how temperature, pressure and volume are related), then you could do a correlation between the predicted value for one column and that column's values, but again from the little physics I can remember your TPV values don't seem to fit that either...

Comment: Anyway, you need to know what you're trying to model before you can answer this question.

Comment: @joanis, thank you very much, but if I understand you correctly, unfortunately, my relationship doesn't fit any of the known ones.

Comment: @joanis, I would be fine with linear interpolation to get the values I need.

Comment: Well, not be eyeballing it, but Google it, you should easily be able to find the relevant relations since I assume you know what T, P and V are, and then add those predicted values by using those relations, and when you inspect that you should be able to draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @joanis, thank you.  If I understand you correctly, I'm having trouble doing that for three values.  I was hoping there might be a Python method that would automate it.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733728/355230) of mine to another question that illustrates how to do linear-interpolation.

Comment: @martineau, thank you. Does your solution mean that the values in each of my arrays have to vary regularly?  They don't.

Comment: Yes, that's the "linear" in that kind of interpolation. The assumption is everything changes to same degree (or percentage).